# Textarea not clickable in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

A expanding textarea is not clickable in the firefox browser. Chrome, IE and mobile browsers work.

```
<div id="image-upload" class="panel">
  <ul class="imagelist-uploader">
   <li>
    <textarea class="inputbox image-comment" name="comment_list[0]" placeholder="Description">Default Text</textarea>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I added the simple code to jsfiddle. Click with chrome at the default text to watch the behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/9hksezsu/

I think it has something do to with the jscode.

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: You put this into a ul - li tag... when you get it out of it, simply copy/paste, it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Javascript code, LINE 60 : remove "disableSelection()" and everything works fine ;)

Comment: thank you very much. Thats it! Do I need this disableSelection() for something else or its just useless?

Comment: looks like it's useless here... maybe just do that when your user is not allowed to edit the selection...

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your list. Remove the textarea from the list and it will work fine.

Comment: Remove javascript and it works fine... so, looks like it's not related to the ul-li

Comment: yes, I removed the ul and the li and made it with div and span. same problem.

Comment: Well, as Julo0sS said, something went wrong through the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `ul` class and it will work fine.